# How to run this jquery code only before and after particular screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this jQuery code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
                var $body = $('body'); //Cache this for performance

                var setBodyScale = function() {
                    var scaleFactor = 0.35,
                        scaleSource = $body.width(),
                        maxScale = 600,
                        minScale = 30;

                    var fontSize = scaleSource * scaleFactor; //Multiply the width of the body by the scaling factor:

                    if (fontSize > maxScale) fontSize = maxScale;
                    if (fontSize < minScale) fontSize = minScale; //Enforce the minimum and maximums

                    $('body').css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
                }

                $(window).resize(function(){
                    setBodyScale();
                });

                //Fire it when the page first loads:
                setBodyScale();
            });
</script>
```

But I want to activate this jQuery code only if `@media only screen and (min-width : 1025px) and (max-width : 2048px)` not after that and not before that.

before 1024px and after 2048px the script should not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the @media configuration from javascript.

What you can is obtain the document's width and check its value:

```
var docWidth = $(document).width();
if (docWidth > 1024 && docWidth < 2048) {
    // execute your function
}
```

I don't know if it required, but if the user resize the window, you might also need to bind to the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    //execute your function
});
```

d.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery resize event :

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  // Check here the width
  width = $(document).width();

  if (width > 1024 && width < 2048) {

      // do your code
   }
});
```

I think you can do what you want with this